# Xamarin sqlite DB always returns nothing

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a sqlite file with some data in it. I added the file to my project where the app.xaml is.
The sqlite file ends up here. "/data/user/0/com.companyname.abm.ablesegeraet/files/.local/share/config.sqlite"

In my View where I want to get the Data I do this to connect to my DB:

```
 SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "config.sqlite"));
```

This works fine so far. Now I want every row in my table called "Tour". At this point I tried everything but I always get no rows...

I tried

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var test = connection.Table<Tour>(); // zero results
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tour";
        var test = command.ExecuteQuery<Tour>(); // Zero results
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var test = connection.Query<Tour>("SELECT * FROM Tour"); //zero reults
    }
```

I also tried those three things but async still no results.
If I Create a Table in code with connection.CreateTable(); and then add a row I get that row when I do a Select. Why doesnt it give me the Data thats already inside the file?

Comment: if you are including a pre-built db file in your project, then the path is NOT `LocalApplicationData`, it will be just the root path

Comment: But it is not in the root path...

Comment: It should be.  What is the build action for the file set to?

Comment: Its set to none and copy to output directory is set to copy always

Comment: use `Content` instead

Comment: It still doenst work. I still says that the table doesnt exist.

Comment: please use `File.Exists("/config.sqlite")` (with and without leading "/") to verify the db file exists in your app bundle - if it works, then use the same when opening your db

Comment: Both times File.Exists returns false

Comment: `File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "config.sqlite"));` returns true

Comment: `SQLiteConnection` will create an empty db at the path if the file does not already exist.

Comment: If I do`new SQLiteConnection("config.sqlite");` it throws an Exception that says "could not open database file: config.sqlite". But if I use `new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "config.sqlite"));` it does not say that

Comment: you can't create files in the app bundle, it is read only.  If you post your code somewhere I will take a quick look at it - this is a very simple problem and should not be this difficult to resolve

Comment: What Code exactly?

Comment: your solution, so I can run it myself

Comment: I dont have time for that rn ill do it later. But thanks already!

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was that the sqlight file was indeed not in `LocalApplicationData` i put it in the root path of my Android device (external storage) and from there it worked.

Comment: that will only work for your device, you cannot deploy a file to an external dir when a user installs from the Play store

Comment: The good thing is the app won't be in the play store. It's for company internal use only.